# What should I focus on to get admission in a Masters programme in the US?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions

I am currently in my second year, pursuing a B.Tech. in Software Engineering, in India. I want to pursue a Masters' in the US in CS/CS-related fields. My area of interest is AI.

I still have two years to go before I will need to apply. So, what should I be working/focusing on in the next two years so that I have a good chance at making it there ? Keeping in mind the fact that i will need scholarships/financing options.

Comment: _My GPA is not very good at the moment._ — Start with that.

Comment: @JeffE Actually our University awards percentages, my score is about 70%. I am not sure what that translates to in terms of GPA. I am in the top 20 percentile of my batch.

Comment: @JeffE any advice beyond that ?

Comment: Since you still have two years to finish your bachelor degree, I strongly advise you to focus on the two years and leave this issue till 1 year or even semester before graduation.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that only a small percentage of Master students get funded.

It's less competitive to get into a Master program than a PhD, mostly because the students pay their own way.

If your grades are not the best you should try to get high GRE, good reccomendation letters, and possibly to some research during your Bachelor.

Are any particular reasons why you chose the US? There are many other school around the world that would cost you less and get a good education as well.

Comment: US has the best research centres as far as AI is concerned (as far as i know). Almost every year about 1-2 people from my institute make it to some of the best/better colleges(CMU, GeorgiaTech, Cornell) there largely financed through scholarships and the like. I  havent really looked at other options considering this + i still have around two years.

Comment: I don't doubt that some Master students are being financed, but as I said they are a really small percentage.